# C++: How to solve this recursive puzzle (subset-sum style)

Tags: c++, recursion

Please give me some pointers on why my code does not work for this assignment. My idea is to have an `index` (param) which is the current place in the Vector, and `target` (param) which is the value of the given index in the array. Then I either move up or down until reaching one of the base cases. But it don´t work.

The main problem is is that it outputs wrong results only false thus far.

[image]

```
bool RecursivePuzzle :: SolvableReal(Vector<int> & squares, int index, int target)
{
if (target == 0 && index == squares.size() ) return true;
if (index >= squares.size()) return false;
if (index < 0) return false;

int goUp = squares[index] + index;
int goDown = squares[index] - index;

return SolvableReal(squares, goUp, squares[index]) ||
       SolvableReal(squares, goDown, squares[index]);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it go into an infinite loop?

Comment: One error is that you're not taking potential infinite loops into account. It may still finish by luck with some configurations, so what do you mean when you say "it doesn't work?" Does it run forever? Does it segfault?

Comment: It does not get caught in an infinite loop unless I have a configuration of [3,0,0,3] (cause it will keep on shifting between those two numbers). But I know this and that´s not the main problem. which is that it outputs wrong results, only false.

Comment: Shouldn't your stop condition just be `index == squares.size() - 1`? (well that or `squares[index] == 0` if we're looking for just a 0). No reason to even have a target parameter as far as I can see and the obvious off-by-one error probably doesn't help either. Anyhow, taking care of cycles is the interesting part here.

Comment: @TomLilletveit The problem lies in your last statement. Due to lazy evaluation, if the goUp part returns true, the goDown isn't evaluated. But as in **step2** of your example, you want to move left though there is a possibility of moving right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not the whole answer, but this part looks wrong:

```
int goUp = squares[index] + index;
int goDown = squares[index] - index;
```

I think it should be

```
int goUp = index + squares[index];
int goDown = index - squares[index];
```

Comment: Whoo! seems that this was the problem, needs further testing but I think so. Atleast I got a correct result now on one of the tests.

Comment: @TomLilletveit the `||` condition at the bottom is a problem as well IMO. See last comment on your question. You consider goDown only if goUp fails.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't your final solution state be compared to size - 1?

```
if (target == 0 && index == squares.size() - 1 ) return true;
```

Comment: @Tom When describing a problem, things like "it gives the wrong result", "it doesn't work" and any other combination of these is rather.. useless. Always give a concrete example, with expected and actual output (you've covered the first two parts, but don't include your actual output) or describe the exact error message (say "I get a stackoverflow for the following input with this stacktrace").